# Animationend event not firing on :after element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, animation

I have an animation set on an :after element and a event handler on the animationend event. However, the animationend event never fires in IE10/IE11.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var testdiv = $('#testid');
    testdiv.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
        document.writeln('Animation has ended');
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Robin_f/R3qEG/

Sincerely hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching the web it has become apparent that IE does not yet support the binding to animation events on a pseudo element. This is made more obvious by the jsFiddle I posted in my original post, which doesn't trigger the event when the animation ends.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in IE or maybe designed like this by DEV team, don't know. A workaround, really hacky, could be to set a fake animation on element to handle IE10/11:

```
#testid {
    animation: fakeAnim ease-in-out 1s 4 alternate;
}

@keyframes fakeAnim {    
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** firefox will fire event twice, should filter it for Firefox to get logic fired only once.

Could be done using:

```
var isIE = !! navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./);
$(document).ready(function () {
    var testdiv = $('#testid');
    testdiv.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function (e) {
        if (!isIE && e.originalEvent.animationName === "fakeAnim") return;
        alert('Animation has ended');
    });
});
```

[See DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjsN5/)

Answer (score -1):

It's because:

> document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment and might break
>   your fiddle.

You can use `console.log()` to debug instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var testdiv = $('#testid');
    testdiv.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
        console.log('Animation has ended');
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3qEG/1/)**

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var testdiv = $('#testid');
    testdiv.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
        $('#testid').append('Animation has ended');
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3qEG/3/)**

Comment: Op's issue is that event is not fired if bound on pseudo element in IE10/11

Comment: Yes, the document.write works just fine :) (even though it's not recommended)